# How to download a Linux version of Terraria on Steam

Tags: steam, terraria, linux

I purchased a copy of Terraria on steam about a year ago to play on my windows laptop. I switched over to a different PC with Linux as its operating system.After downloading Steam,Steam only downloads the windows version of the game.After referring to the  internet, I got to know about  the Terraria Mac and Linux open beta which is supposed to be an option in library>Terraria>Properties>Betas which does not exists and shows only one option called OPT OUT OF ALL BETA PROGRAMS. I've tried Wine and PlayOnLinux but both don't work for me. Any help?

Comment: First of all: since the question is specific to Terraria, the title needs to be as well. Secondly, I have been using the M + L open beta on my mac. I checked the beta list like you did above and I didn't see the M+L beta option. In fact, when I clicked out of the list to close it, it defaulted to the "None" option. I don't know if it still works though, haven't tried it. I'll do a bit more research.

Comment: So I did a bit more research (I honestly couldn't find a whole lot), but I found [this thread](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/terraria-1-3-0-7-mac-linux-open-beta.27418/page-28) in which someone says that they closed the M+L open beta. A shame and dissapointment, really, that they closed it for Linux and the game doesn't support it anymore.

Comment: @PlanetAlexander If you have suggestions for editing the question/title, go ahead and submit an edit!

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the Steam client for linux that best suits your distribution (latest version found [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux#Native_Steam_on_Linux)) and make sure it has all prerequisites to run.
2. Start the steam client as your regular desktop user and sign in to steam using your steam credentials.
3. If the game you want to play is supported by steam under SteamOS/Linux, it should be marked as such in your library and you'll be able to install it the usual way. (Terraria is marked as such so you should be good.)
4. Enjoy your game.

Comment: The problem is Terraria is no longer supported on Linux, meaning it is unplayable on that platform.

Comment: Even if I install terraria it downloads the Windows version. And if I try to open it my PC crashes

Comment: @PlanetAlexander Source? It works fine here on Kubuntu 17.10. It also has the SteamOS (Linux) icon on the store page

Comment: I just yesterday played with my kids, one of which was using a Linux Mint 17.3 laptop. It ran fine out of the box with Steam's linux client.